# C++ code without having to declare temporary at the outer scope

Tags: c++

Is there any way to write following code without using the temporary "result"?

```
result = func();
if(result == -1)
        return func2();
else
    return result;
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason you need to? You could tighten it up a bit using `return (result = func()) == -1 ? func2() : result;`.

Comment: I just wanted to see if there are any suggestions on not having to declare the result in main scope. I will change how the question is phrased. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FYI, if your goal is to avoid polluting the outer scope with the temporary name (and you don't want to enclose everything in a {} block), in c++17 we have the *if statement with initializer*:

```
if( auto result = func(); result == -1 )
    return func2();
else
    return result;
```

and, almost(*) just for fun, yet another one-liner could be

```
[result=func()]{ return (result == -1) ? func2() : result; }(); // requires c++14, or
[](auto result){ return (result == -1) ? func2() : result; }(func());
```

(*) IMO, such a thing may be useful when you want to focus readability on the logic in the lambda without pollution from initialization statements...

Comment: Lambda-version deserves a +1

Comment: Yes! you got it right. That was my goal i.e. not to declare the result in the outer scope, as it is only one line where I would use it. I really like the if statement with the initializer, I was not aware of that. And a big thumbs up for the lambda function suggestion, I was trying to figure out how could I use lambda here. I understood the first lamda statement. Not sure how the second one works.

Comment: @patronus, FYI the first one uses a *generalized lambda capture* to make result a member of the closure object; the second uses a *generic lambda* to generically pass result as a function parameter (if I knew result type I could have just written, say, int result instead)

Answer (score 8):

No.

But I'd simplify to

```
result = func();
if(result == -1)
        return func2();
return result;
```

You could use a ternary but I don't think it makes things clearer.

```
result = func();
return (result == -1) ? func2() : result;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I agree not using else is definitely a good simplification. Also I am aware I could use the ternary operator instead, I wanted to see if I could do it without having to declare the result in the main scope.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

```
 return (func() == -1) ? func2() : func();
```

**EDIT: Yes you can but be careful**

As @Jarod42 said:

You can try to be fancy and not use a temporary value but you can risk having different results (if using `rand`).

`func()` can be called twice and may result in performance issues.

**tldr:** you can only if func() is an idempotent function.

http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/idempotency.html

Comment: But `func` is called twice: it might return different value (as `rand`) or have side effect (as `std::cout << "hi";`) or be computation intensive.

Comment: You are right. func() will be called twice and can return different values (using rand). I thought the the result of func() would be stored. My bad

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned. I want to avoid calling func() twice :)